# How do I access parent property from subclass? PHP

Tags: php, class, variables, parent

I have an issue accessing top level variables from sub-level class.
Here's an example...

Application.php:

```
class Application {
    var $config;
    var $db;

    function __construct() {
        include_once('Configuration.php');
        include_once('Database.php');
        $this->config   = new Configuration;
        $this->db       = new Database;
    }
}
```

Configuration.php:

```
class Configuration {
    var $dbhost = 'localhost';
}
```

Database.php:

```
class Database {
    function __construct() {
        echo parent::config->dbhost;
    }
}
```

It is clear to me that usage of **parent** is wrong here as the subclass does not extend the parent class, but how do I access it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a `Base` class that in its construct creates a `$db` link. Then let all classes that require database access extend that class. Your nomenclature here with "parent class" is incorrect.

```
class Base {
   private $db;   // Make it read-only

   function __construct() {
      $this->db = DB::connect();    // It's a good practice making this method static
   }

   function __get($property) {
      return $this->$property;
   }
}

class Application {
    public $config;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        require_once 'Configuration.php';
        require_once 'Database.php';
        $this->config   = new Configuration();
    }

    function random_function() {
       $this->db(....)    // Has full access to the $db link
    }
}
```

Comment: This will make me have more code in my main file. `code`include('Base.php'); include('Application.php');... `code`

Comment: silkfire, I got no idea how you write, but personally I prefer to keep as less code as possible outside of my classes and write as less as possible always, saving my time and writing code faster. Besides, the more code - the more server load. Might not be an argument for you though.

Comment: It's okay to have lots of code as long as it is clean, effective and easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

The parent notation is used to access the parent of the object in the object hierarchy. What you are doing here is trying to get at the caller, not the parent

The way that you would do this is to pass in an instance of your configuration to the database object.

```
    class Database {
          protected $config;

          public function __construct(Configuration $config){
                $this->config = $config;
          }

          public function connect(){
                //use properties like $this->config->username to establish your connection. 
          }
    }
```

The parent notation is used when you extend a class and make a child class to call methods on the parent .

```
    class MySuperCoolDatabase extends Database {
          protected $is_awesome; 

          public function __construct(Configuration $config){
               // do all the normal database config stuff
               parent::__construct($config);
               // make it awesome
               $this->is_awesome = true;
          }
    }
```

This defines a child class, which is a type definition that serves the same role as the base class with a slightly different implementation. Instances of this can still be said to be a Database.... just a different kinds of database.

Comment: As I understand, in this case there will be a total of two instances of Configuration class object - one in Application class and one in Database class. This way requiring twice more server resources to run the script? This one is a simple one, but there are more complicated scripts and server resources can not be wasted this way.

Comment: This is not true... the only way that will occur is if you create two configuration objects using the new keyword. This will create two references to the same Configuration Object.

Comment: This method of passing an object into another object is called constructor dependency injection and makes it your database class more reusable, because now your database class isn't bound to any specific implementation of Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Well, although I think that Orangepills answer is better. If you dont want to use it and since all variables are public, you could simply pass the variable like this:

```
class Application {
    var $config;
    var $db;

    function __construct() {
        include_once('Configuration.php');
        include_once('Database.php');
        $this->config   = new Configuration;
        $this->db       = new Database($this->config->dbhost);
    }
}

class Configuration {
    var $dbhost = 'localhost';
}

class Database {
    function __construct($dbhost) {
        echo $dbhost;
    }
}
```